# async await vs TaskFactory.StartNew and WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I've got a NServiceBus host that goes and downloads a whole bunch of data once a message comes through about a particular users account. One data file is about 3Mb (myob - via a webservice call) and another is about 2Mb (restful endpoint, quite fast!). To avoid waiting around for long, I've wrapped the two download calls like this:

```
var myobBlock = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myobService.GetDataForUser(accountId, datablockId, CurrencyFormat.IgnoreValidator));
var account = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => accountService.DownloadMetaAccount(accountId, securityContext));

Task.WaitAll(myobBlock, account);

var myobData = myobBlock.Result;
var accountData = account.Result;
//...Process AccountData Object using myobData object
```

I'm wondering what the benefits are for using the new async/await patterns are here compared to the TPL-esque method I've got above. Reading Stephen Clearys notes, it seems that the above would cause the thread to sit there waiting, where as Async/Await would continue and release the thread for other work.

How would you rewrite that within the context of Async/Await and would it be beneficial? We have lots of accounts to process but its once MSMQ message per account (end of FY reporting) or per-request (ad-hoc when a customer calls up and wants their report)

Comment: Do GetDataForUser and DownloadMetaAccount expose async apis?

Comment: they do not, myobService is a wrapper around a third party client, accountservice is ours.

Comment: You can wrap the response from your GetDataForUser in a TaskCompletionSource<>
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/creating-tasks.html

Comment: Had a look at that, but it would mean I'd have to change the method to be decorated as async that runs the above code I presume? I'm implementing an interface that can't modify the method signature on :(

Comment: You can save three blocked threads for the duration of the web service work by using async. If you do not need to save them async will give you zero benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of using `async/await` is that given a true async api (One which doesn't call sync methods over async using `Task.Run` and the likes, but does true async I/O work) you can avoid the allocation of any unnecessary Threads which simply waste resources only to wait on blocking I/O operations.

Lets imagine both your service methods exposed an `async` api, you could do the following instead of using two ThreadPool threads:

```
var myobBlock = myobService.GetDataForUserAsync(accountId, datablockId, CurrencyFormat.IgnoreValidator));

var account = accountService.DownloadMetaAccountAsync(accountId, securityContext));

// await till both async operations complete
await Task.WhenAll(myobBlock, account);
```

What will happen is that execution will yield back to the calling method until both tasks complete. When they do, continuation will resume via IOCP onto the assigned `SynchronizationContext` if needed.

Comment: I find that it's best to start at the "leaves" and work your way outwards. You can rebuild your web service proxy to get asynchronous methods, and use `HttpClient` for the REST API. With these in place, making your service methods asynchronous is straightforward.

Comment: That's a great explanation Yuval, unfortunately I'm not reppy enough to upvote you! @StephenCleary, is there a way we can still use async/await (especially after YuvalItzchakov's explanation) without touching the proxy or rest APIs?

Comment: @Keerthi: If this is a server, then no. If this is a client app, then you can "cheat" by just wrapping things in a `Task.Run` and awaiting that. Another solution to consider is TPL Dataflow.

Comment: @Keerthi If its good enough and meets your needs, you can mark it as answer.